# LWC - Async/Await but value hasn't returned

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, asynchronous, lightning-combobox

I have 2 picklists. When the first picklist get clicked, it will captured the value and pass to the second picklist.

Right now, I'm using async/await and also try to call it imperative but it did not work

Apex controller:

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String,String> getPicklistTypeFields(String strObjectName) {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> detail = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String,String> mapOfPicklistTypeFields = new  Map<String,String>();
        for(Schema.SObjectField fields :detail.get(strObjectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().Values()) {
            If(fields.getDescribe().getType() == Schema.DisplayType.PICKLIST) { 
                mapOfPicklistTypeFields.put(fields.getDescribe().getLabel(), fields.getDescribe().getName());
            }
        }
        return mapOfPicklistTypeFields;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static Map<String,String> getValueForSelectedPicklistField(string strObjectName, string selectedField){
        try {
            System.debug('Object Name '+strObjectName);
            System.debug('Selected Field '+selectedField);
            Map<String,String> options = new  Map<String,String>(); 
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mapFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(strObjectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult pickFieldResult = mapFields.get(selectedField).getDescribe();   
            List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistFields1 = pickFieldResult.getPicklistValues();
                for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListFields2 : picklistFields1)
                {
                    options.put(pickListFields2.getLabel(),pickListFields2.getValue());
                }       
            return options;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="slds-card">
        <lightning-combobox name="fieldList" label="Group By" onchange={getPicklistFieldsOptions} options={lstOfPicklistFields} placeholder="Select Field"></lightning-combobox>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-card">
        <lightning-combobox name="fieldList" label='Available values' options={objectFieldOptionsList} placeholder="Select Field"></lightning-combobox>
    </div>
```

JS code:

```
fieldSelectedToGetPicklistTypeField = '';
    getPicklistFieldsOptions(event) { 
        this.fieldSelectedToGetPicklistTypeField = event.detail.value;
        console.log('Value'+ this.fieldSelectedToGetPicklistTypeField);
        this.getPicklistValuesForSelectedPicklistField();
    }
    
    @track objectFieldOptionsList = [];
    async getPicklistValuesForSelectedPicklistField() {
        await getValueForSelectedPicklistField({ strObjectName: '$objectApiName', selectedField: this.fieldSelectedToGetPicklistTypeField })
        .then((result) => {
          if (result) {
              this.objectFieldOptionsList = [];
            for (let key in result) {
                this.objectFieldOptionsList.push({ label: key, value: result[key] });
            }
             
          } 
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error in getting pickist values')
        })
    }
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: What's happening? What's not working?  Are you getting any errors?  Please edit your question with more detail about exactly where you're stuck, or this question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of how you are passing in the input parameter to your apex class. You cannot use the '$objectApiName' inside a function.  ***I will edit this post to be more detailed***

for the code below, I am assuming you have @api objectApiName, at the top of your JS somewhere.

JS

```
fieldSelectedToGetPicklistTypeField = '';
    getPicklistFieldsOptions(event) { 
        this.fieldSelectedToGetPicklistTypeField = event.detail.value;
        console.log('Value'+ this.fieldSelectedToGetPicklistTypeField);
        this.getPicklistValuesForSelectedPicklistField();
    }
    
    @track objectFieldOptionsList = [];
    async getPicklistValuesForSelectedPicklistField() {
        await getValueForSelectedPicklistField({ strObjectName: this.objectApiName, selectedField: this.fieldSelectedToGetPicklistTypeField })
        .then((result) => {
          if (result) {
              this.objectFieldOptionsList = [];
            for (let key in result) {
                this.objectFieldOptionsList.push({ label: key, value: result[key] });
            }
             
          } 
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error in getting pickist values')
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the async/await options this way. When you call a method with `await`, the result is returned to the caller, not asynchronously.

For example, your picklist values would be retrieved this way using `await`:

```js
const result = await myAsyncMethod();
```

You don't need this, however. You can keep your code and remove the `async` and `await` keywords and do the resolving asynchronously (as your code is apparently ready to do).

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out and give feedback. 
I did as the comment above recommended and it also works.